# How to read each line in .tfvars and export key value as environmental var in bash?

Tags: bash, terraform

I want to read from .tfvars which is variables_file_2 and export each variable (key) and value of it as environmental variable in bash so I can access it in my script

```bash
grep "^[^#]" "${variables_file_2}" > manifest.tfvars

while read line;
do
    export "$(echo "${line}" | tr -d "\"")"
done < manifest.tfvars
```

Currently getting

> `` export: `{={': not a valid identifier ``

as error.

sample of .tfvars is

```
region = "us-east-2"
```

Comment: If you could post a simple input and desired output, then that would help others to understand what `.tfvars` looks like...

Comment: Can't help without an accurate sample of the content of `$variables_file_2`

Comment: region = "us-east-2"

Comment: Why do you want that in your script?

Answer (score 1):

The code

```
grep "^[^#]" "${variables_file_2}" > manifest.tfvars
```

Looks like you're trying to remove/delete lines starting with a `#`

and the `tr` seems like trying to delete the quotes around the assignment after the `=` sign.

Something like this might do it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo export -- "$line"
done < <(sed '/^#/d;s/ = /=/;s/"//g' "${variables_file_2}")
```

---

With the assumption that the input from `"${variables_file_2}"` is something like.

```
#
region = "us-east-2"
#
```

With

```
sed '/^#/d;s/ = /=/;s/"//g' "${variables_file_2}"
```

Or even like

```
sed '/^#/d;s/^\([^ ]*\) = "\([^"].*\)"/\1=\2/' "${variables_file_2}"
```

The output should be.

```
region=us-east-2
```

- Remove the `echo` if you're ok with the output.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use something more robust:

```bash
LANG=C awk -v OFS='=' '
    $1 ~ /^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*$/ && $2 == "=" && match($0,/".*"/) {
        print $1, substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-2)
    }
' "${variables_file_2}" > manifest.tfvars

while IFS='=' read -r var value
do
    export "$var"="$value"
done < manifest.tfvars
```

<sup>**note:** the `awk` assumes that the `=` are always surrounded by at least a space character</sup>